# Paper recommendation with examples

Tags: fixed-income, programming, numerical-methods, financial-engineering

Could you please advise me some papers/working documents with applications mainly focused on Fixed Income/Financial Engineering (Numerical Methods)  as the one in the link below? Preferably on Matlab, but not necessarily.

https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144500378302

And simple implementation of solving PDE with finite difference method would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend 2 sets of classical books in the field of financial engineering

- "The Wilmott": https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Paul+Wilmott+on+Quantitative+Finance%2C+3+Volume+Set%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118836835
- "The Piterbarg": https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11408-011-0157-y

Answer (score 1):

Numerical Methods in Finance and Economics from Brandimarte has what you're looking for (in Matlab, too).

[https://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Methods-Finance-Economics-MATLAB-Based/dp/0471745030](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471745030)

Comment: Thank you I’ll check it as soon as possible.